# ZF2 custom logfile, set username

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-log

How can I make custom log (using Zend2) and set username to every log event.
Here is my example how I`m trying:

```
public function log( )
{

    $log_file = 'path/to/logfile.log';

    $format = '%timestamp% %priorityName% (%username%) %message%';
    $formatter = new Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple($format);
    $formatter->setDateTimeFormat('H:i:s');

    $formatter->format( array('username'=> SET_USER_NAME ));

    $logWriter = new LogWriter($log_file);
    $logWriter->setFormatter($formatter);

    $logger = new Logger;
    $logger->addWriter( $logWriter );

    return $logger;
}
```

I tried the following

```
$this->log()->info(" Log message " );
```

And result is:

```
11:33:54 INFO (%username%) Log message
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [third parameter of log method](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Log.Logger.html#log) `extra` - array of extra data, which are converted to json and automatically added to log message by formatter ([Zend\Log\Formatter\Simple::format](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7688fab93de0b94c3469c798cbb2d36d301bfce3/library/Zend/Log/Formatter/Simple.php#L66-L70))

Simple example:

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream('php://output');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$logger->info('Informational message', ['user' => 'administrator']);
```

Outputs something like this:

```
2014-12-01T13:00:00+00:00 INFO (6): Informational message {"user":"administrator"}
```